# Need help with a SQL UDF?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

On SQL 2000:

I am trying to write a dynamic UDF that will pull the values of one of five fields depending on the input criteria. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fBudgetBid ( @sJob int, @sCO nvarchar(10), @sCat nvarchar(10) )
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @ERC float
  Set @ERC = Case @sCat
  WHEN 'Field' Then Select [Field] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO  
  WHEN 'Eng' Then Select [Eng] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO  
  WHEN 'PM' Then Select [PM] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO  
  WHEN 'Shop' Then Select [Shop] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO  
  WHEN 'Purch' Then Select [Purch] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO  
  END
  Return @ERC
END
```

I have used a single SELECT statement to return a value, and I have used the CASE WHEN THEN structure to return hard-coded values. Not having any luck blending the two. ** The names have been changed to protect the innocent. **

UPDATE: Got it to work as below. The parentheses made all the difference in the world.

```
BEGIN
 Return (Case @sCat
  WHEN 'Field' Then (Select [Field] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO)
  WHEN 'Eng' Then (Select [Eng] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO)  
  WHEN 'PM' Then (Select [PM] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO)
  WHEN 'Shop' Then (Select [Shop] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [CO] = @sCO)  
  WHEN 'Purch' Then (Select [Purch] From [dbo].[Estimate] Where [Job] = @sJob AND [] ] = @sCO)
  END)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, see if it answer your requirement.

```
DEClARE @ERC FLOAT

SELECT @ERC = CASE @sCat WHEN 'Field' THEN [Field] 
             WHEN 'Eng' THEN [Eng] 
             WHEN 'PM' THEN [PM] 
             WHEN 'Shop' THEN [Shop] 
             WHEN 'Purch' THEN [Purch] END
FROM [dbo].[Estimate] 
WHERE [Job] = @sJob 
AND [CO] = @sCO  

RETURN @ERC
```